# Always show Part Stack in Eclipse E4

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my Eclipse E4 application I hava a part stack with some parts in it.
Now I need a way to always show the part stack (also when all the parts in it are closed by the user).

How can I provide this feature in my E4 application?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the value `NoAutoCollapse` to the Tags of the Part Stack that should always be shown.

[image: NoAutoCollapse tags]

Comment: I have the same issue and tried your solution but it didn't work. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Ask a new question showng exactly what you have done